# specify current week based on day of week asp.net mvc 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Currently I'm trying to make a query that based on the day of week gets movies out of the database of that week. 
So a movie week is from Thursday to next Wednesday. 
When its Sunday, I only want movies from Sunday to Wednesday. 
If its Tuesday, I only want movies from Tuesday to Wednesday etc. 
I'm really getting stuck on what you can and cannot do in asp any suggestions?

Here's my code so far:

```
public IEnumerable<Viewing> GetUpcomingWeekViews()
    {
        var viewingList1 = _efdbContext.Viewing.ToList();

        DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
        var viewingList = _efdbContext.Viewing.ToList();

        DateTime startOfWeek = DateTime.Now.

        return viewingList.Where(v => (
            v.StartTime.Date == currentDate.Date) &&
            (v.StartTime.TimeOfDay > currentDate.TimeOfDay)
        ).OrderBy(v => v.StartTime);
    }
```

Comment: You can use the [DateTime.DayOfWeek](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek(v=vs.110).aspx) property to do you calculations

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DayOfWeek` property of `DateTime`:

```
var date = DateTime.Now;
var currentWeekday = (int)date.DayOfWeek;
const int wednesday = 3; // sunday is 0

var offset = 0; 
// if today is before wednesday, go to next wednesday
if (currentWeekday < wednesday) {
    offset = wednesday - currentWeekday;
}
// if today is wednesday, add a whole week till next wednesday
if(currentWeekday == wednesday) {
    offset = 7;
}
// if today is after wednesday, go to wednesday in a week
if(currentWeekday > wednesday) {
    offset = wednesday - currentWeekday + 7;
}

var nextWednesday = date.AddDays(offset);
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9cP08D)

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the offset from Current date to desired date using `DateOfWeek`

```
public int CalculateOffset(DayOfWeek current, DayOfWeek desired) {
    // f( c, d ) = [7 - (c - d)] mod 7
    // f( c, d ) = [7 - c + d] mod 7
    // c is current day of week and 0 <= c < 7
    // d is desired day of the week and 0 <= d < 7
    int c = (int)current;
    int d = (int)desired;
    int offset = (7 - c + d) % 7;
    return offset == 0 ? 7 : offset;
}
```

And add that offset to the `Date` of the current `DateTime`

```
public IEnumerable<Viewing> GetUpcomingWeekViews(DayOfWeek desiredDayOfWeek = DayOfWeek.Thursday) {
    DateTime minStartTime = DateTime.Now;
    var currentDayOfWeek = minStartTime.DayOfWeek;

    int offset = CalculateOffset(currentDayOfWeek, desiredDayOfWeek);

    DateTime maxStartTime = minStartTime.Date.AddDays(offset);

    var viewingList = dbContext.Viewing.ToList();

    return viewingList
        .Where(v => minStartTime <= v.StartTime && v.StartTime < maxStartTime)
        .OrderBy(v => v.StartTime);
}
```